# How do I merge my 2 Ask Ubuntu Accounts?

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts

I have just realized I have 2 AU accounts, I cant recall how this happened but I did change my e-mail address recently.  How do i go about merging them, is this something you can help me with?

- Primary User ID: 53498
- Old Account (to be removed when merged): 51556

Comment: I'll merge it now.

Comment: And it's done !

Comment: Nice Job Oli, Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated [in comments](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/2995/how-do-i-merge-my-2-ask-ubuntu-accounts#comment4123_2995) this has been fixed and can be considered as answered.